# Salesforce Field value not visible on web page

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code, salesforce-communities

I have a field Expiration Date in an Object, also I have an actual Expiration Date(value) in it for an account for which I'd be using the field, also when I do have the field added on the page layout but, when I run the page the value of the field is not visible on the actual web page despite the value being present. I am an absolute novice when it comes to Salesforce, can someone please help me, do I need to change the code or formula or something else?

Answer (score 0):

How exactly it doesn't show up? I know, stupid question.

If you view the record page and can see the field label ("Expiration Date") but there's no value next to it - well, there's really no value. Edit it, save, see again. If it was supposed to come from some data load - maybe there were errors. If it's a calculated field (formula) - it might have bugs in it or some other field it depends on is empty.

If you can see the field in page layout editor but on actual record you can't see both the field label and value - it's a permissions thing. Go to Setup -> Profiles -> System Administrator -> Object Settings -> Account and check "read" checkbox next to your field. You might have to do same for profiles of your end users.

If that doesn't help - can you edit and post some screenshots?

Comment: I'd love to share screenshots here but, it not giving me an option to post any photos I guess, can I message you personally or something like that?

Comment: Post on imgur or something like that and put links in here? Or we could try zoom, google meet etc. Or poke me on https://www.linkedin.com/in/tomasz-duda. I'm in UK, GMT + 1